# Generating text_input after selecting "Other" on Phoenix form

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to generate a text_input in Phoenix.HTML for a form field after a user selects "Other" from my dropdown `<select>`, but I'm unsure of the syntax for doing so in Phoenix markup

I imagine it is something with an if or case statement, perhaps in the opts for select, but again I am unsure

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= label f, :field, class: "control-label" %>
<%= select f, :field, [..."Other"], prompt: "Select your field", class: "form-control" %>
<%= error_tag f, :field %>
<%= if "Other" do %>
  <%= text_input f, :field, class: "form-control" %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: “after a user selects "Other" from my dropdown”—this can not be done without client-side script aka javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. What you may do is to always generate this field but hide it (using css) before it's required and then just use some JS to show it when it's needed or skip generating on the server side at all and do it on the client side, again with help of JavaScript.

Comment: Makes sense -- decided to generate it client-side, as the field in question is required and a display:hidden required field requires more code to input (mirroring values) than just a client-side gen'd field. Thank you!